# How to convert geopoint longitude +latitude to double?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, casting

I am retrieving the center of a map view and i need to pass the longs and lats as doubles to my server for testing against the database .

How would i go about converting  mapView.getMapCenter().getLongitudeE6() to a double ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling `mapView.getMapCenter()` returns a `GeoPoint`. `GeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()` and `GeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()` both return microdegrees (basically degrees * 1E6).

So, in Java, to convert microdegrees to degrees simply do:

```
public static double microDegreesToDegrees(int microDegrees) {
    return microDegrees / 1E6;
}
```