# Converting Int latitude and longitude to double (like Geopoint)

Tags: c#, int, double, geopoints

I have this two int values (w 25456819, s 12088051).

I need to know how can i convert them to latitude and longitude values in double.

The final result of this should be something like this:

- w 25456819 = -33,xxxxxx
- s 12088051 = -70,xxxxxx

But i can't find any clue for this, the accurate answer then i have found it's something about google's Geopoint, this one recives two int values in his constructor. Then when you use the **geopoint** object you can get the lat and long values.

I have tried to find any library or class for **c sharp**, but i haven't had any luck on that.

I'll really apreciate any help.

Best regards.

Comment: Find the equation and code it. There is no built in class, you should try it yourself before coming to ask for help.

Comment: It's not even an equation. They're just microdegrees; it's a scaling factor of a million. It's [already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427098/how-to-convert-geopoint-longitude-latitude-to-double).